# Swapping two numbers using only two variables

Tags: algorithm, swap

How is it performing swapping?

> a=a+b
>
> b=a+b
>
> a=b+a

I don't agree that it's swap to a book!!!

The book options include "complements of values of a and b" ,"negate  and b".Hope these options aren't satisfying it too???

Comment: Please check with an original of the book: is there any circle enclosing the cross (⊕)? That would signify not an arithmetic operation on variable values, but the bit-wise exclusive-or (ExOr or EXOR). (The sequence `a = a⊕b` ... being the more common "swap values of two registers, writing one register at a time and not using a third"). (what does `The book options` mean?

Comment: i hope so a typo in book...thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The swap is performed using XOR, which is typically written as a plus within a circle; for example:

```
a := 5
b := 7

a := a xor b (2)
b := a xor b (5)
a := b xor a (7)
```

Answer (score 11):

The correct algorithm should be:

```
a = a + b 
b = a - b
a = a - b
```

Comment: yes i agree with what u say but the book quoted it like above

Comment: Khan, If you already know the book's quote is, in fact, *not* performing the swap, and you already know what the swap code looks like, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I recently underwent an interview for java fresher, the interviewer asked me to perform swapping of two numbers (but in one line).

Swapping of two numbers can be performed in one line also, without using a temp variable.

The logic is really simple,

x is added with y in the same line, y is assigned as x which is subtracted by their sum.

after performing this one line arithmetics the numbers were swapped. (only in one line)

```
public class SwapInOneLine {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 10; int y = 20;
    System.out.println("Before Swaping: x = " + x + " and y= " + y);
    x = x + y - (y = x);
    System.out.println("After Swaping: x = " + x + " and y= " + y);
}}
```

**output:**

> Before Swaping: x = 10 and y= 20
>
> After Swaping: x = 20 and y= 10

Answer (score 0):

We can use **XOR (^)** for this.
Advantage of XOR : As XOR works on **bit level**, it takes very less amount of time than any other operations.
If a = 5 and b = 7
then to swap :

**a = a ^ b**

**b = a ^ b**

**a = a ^ b**

Where **'^'** means **XOR**.
Result :
a = 7 and b = 5

Answer (score -1):

Actually, it can be done by two ways:

```
int a = 5, b = 10;
```

**Using Addition(+) and Subtraction(-)**

```
a = a + b;
b = a - b;
a = a - b;
```

**Using Multiple(*) and Division(/)**

```
a = a * b;
b = a / b;
a = a / b;
```

Comment: @Logman In that situation you should opt for the first one, using addition and subtraction.

Comment: Personally I preferred xor solution but to more complex type one should use temporary variable anyway. You also should mention that `a=a+b;` in some languages can cause overflow error. For instance in c# you need to provide `unchecked` keyword to make it work.